# Binding BeanItemContainer within is array to the table

Tags: java, arrays, binding, vaadin

I have BeanItemContainer which I would like to bind as a data source in my table.
BeanItemContainer has inside bean within is an array.
How could I do this ?

Below is my bean (POJO) within is nested the array:

```
private EmployeesArray[] employeesArray;

public EmployeesArray[] getEmployeesArray() {
    return employeesArray;
}

public void setEmployeesArray (EmployeesArray[] employeesArray) {
    this.employeesArray = employeesArray;
}

public EmployeesListPOJO(){ 
}
```

And here is the nested array:

```
private String lastname;
private String firstname;

public String getLastname () {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname (String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getFirstname () {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname (String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ClassPojo [lastname = "+lastname+", firstname = "+firstname+"]";
}

public EmployeesArray(){
}
```

And here's my attempt to bind it to the table:

```
BeanItemContainer<EmployeesListPOJO> container = new BeanItemContainer<EmployeesListPOJO>(EmployeesListPOJO.class);

Table table = new Table();
table.setContainerDataSource(container);
table.setVisibleColumns(new String[] {"employeesArray"});
table.setColumnHeader("employeesArray", "First name", "Last name");`
```

I would like to have two column headers in my table: "First name" and "Last name"
which are associated to fields `firstname` and `lastname` in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not trying to be condescending, but I believe there are a few issues with this code, so let's tackle them 1 by 1:

1. The `EmployeesArray` class should probably be named `Employee` since it holds employee data, and your array variable would become `Employee[] employees`.
2. Since you want to display employees in your table, you should have a corresponding container: `BeanItemContainer<Employee> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(Employee.class);`
3. If `EmployeesListPOJO` can not be changed, you'll then need to iterate over the array and add each employee bean to the container with `container.addBean(employees[i]);`. Or, if you can change it to a collection instead you can just simply call `container.addAll(employees);`. Also probably `EmployeesListPOJO` should have a friendlier name but I don't know the whole context so it's up to you

Putting it all together:

```
    // create the table
    Table table = new Table()

    // and the appropriate data holder 
    BeanItemContainer<Employee> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(Employee.class);
    table.setContainerDataSource(container);

    // set desired headers
    table.setColumnHeaders("First name", "Last name");

    // get all of the employees to display
    employees = employeesListPOJO.getEmployeesArray();

    // add each employee to the container
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        container.addBean(employees[i]);
    }

    // or if you can get a collection/list of employees
    // container.addAll(employeesListPOJO.getEmployees());
```

With:

```
public class Employee {

    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;

    public Employee(String lastname, String firstname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname () {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname (String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFirstname () {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname (String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [lastname = "+lastname+", firstname = "+firstname+"]";
    }
}
```

Should result in

[image: Employee table]

**P.S. 1:** You can also find more information in the [Vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html#datamodel.container.beanitemcontainer)

**P.S. 2:** If you're working with the latest Vaadin versions (7.4.0 +) and depending on your needs, I suggest taking a look at the newer [Grid component](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.grid.html) which is supposed to be more flexible than its older counterpart the table. You can see its features in action on the [sampler site](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Morfic.
Cheers.